# The acceleration of particle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, reference-frames

> The acceleration of a particle as seen from two frames S1 and S2 have equal magnitude 4m/s².
>
> a. The frames must be at rest with respect to each other.
> b. The frames may be moving with respect to each other but neither should be accelerated with respect to the other.
> c. The acceleration of S2 with respect to S1 may either be zero or 8m/s².
> d. The acceleration of S2 with respect to S1 may be anything between zero and 8m/s².

The answer is (d). I don't understand how could it be between zero and 8m/s².

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the question must be wanting you to work in more than one dimension. If the accelerations are all in the same direction, you're right that the relative accelerations of the two frames must be either $0$ or $8$ $m/s^2$. Working in 2D, however:

Take the ball to be under no acceleration (at rest, if you like). If $S_1$ has acceleration $\vec{a_1} = 4 \; m/s^2 \; \hat{x}$ and $S_2$ has acceleration $\vec{a_2} = 4 \; m/s^2 \; \hat{y}$, then in both frames the particle will be seen to accelerate at $4 \; m/s^2$. However, the magnitude of their relative acceleration is 
$$|\vec{a_2}-\vec{a_1}| = |4 \; m/s^2 \; \hat{y}-4 \; m/s^2 \; \hat{x}| = 4\sqrt{2} \; m/s^2 \approx 5.66 \; m/s^2$$

And similarly, by varying the angle between $\vec{a_1}$ and $\vec{a_2}$, you can get any relative acceleration you like in the given range. The $0 \; m/s^2$ case is when the frames accelerate in the same direction, and the $8\; m/s^2$ case is when they accelerate in opposite directions.